# Django how to handle 2 Post Requests

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I have a micro ticket system. The user has information about the ticket, a button to mark as solved/mark as waiting and a message box to add new messages in to the ticket for the admin.

You can ignore the most stuff in the forms, important are the GET/POST requests of the forms.

\\views.py

```
def ticket_system_view(request, id):
    obj = Ticket.objects.get(id=id)

    waiting_message = "Mark as 'Waiting'"
    solved_message = "Mark as 'Solved'"

    if obj.reopened_counter > 5:
        solved_message = 'Ticked solved forever'
        waiting_message = 'Ticked solved forever'

    button_form = TicketSolved(request.POST)
    time.sleep(2)

    if button_form.is_valid:
        obj.reopened_counter += 1
        if obj.reopened_counter > 5:
            obj.ticket_waiting = True
            obj.ticket_solved = False

        if obj.ticket_waiting == False and obj.ticket_solved == True:
            obj.ticket_waiting = True
            obj.ticket_solved = False
        else:
            obj.ticket_waiting = False
            obj.ticket_solved = True
        obj.save()


    user_form = TicketMessagesForm(
        request.POST, instance=TicketMessages(id=id))
    if user_form.is_valid():
        instance = user_form.save(commit=False)
        #this form doesnt work yes
        instance.save()

    return render(request, 'ticket-system.html', {'obj': obj, 'waiting_message': waiting_message, 'solved_message': solved_message, 'button_form': button_form, 'user_form': user_form})
```

\\forms.py

```
class TicketSolved(forms.Form):
    delete = forms.CharField(
        label='', max_length=0).widget = forms.HiddenInput()


class TicketMessagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TicketMessages

        fields = (
            'user_message',
        )
```

\\models.py if you need

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    creator_adress = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ticket_waiting = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ticket_solved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reopened_counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class TicketMessages(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    admin_message = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
    user_message = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
```

Each time the user sets the ticket to Solved/Waiting, a counter counts. When the counter reaches 5, the ticket is automatically marked as solved to avoid spam.

Problem:
I have Two forms in the view
-user_form for the messages of the user
-button_form for the form which contains only the counter button

Actually I don't need a form for button_form, but that doesn't matter for now.

If I now send user_form, button_form is also sent and so the counter counts up. How do I change my code so that when I send user_form, only user_form is sent and button_form is not? And the other way around. There more problems like the not working user_form but first things first.

Thank you very much! :^)

Edit:
Here is the HTML File where display the forms

```
{% if obj.user != request.user %}
<p>Page Not Found</p>

{% else %}
<p>Ticket ID {{obj.id}}</p>

{{ obj.title }} {{ obj.description }} {% endif %}
<br></br>

<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ button_form }}
  <button {% if obj.reopened_counter > 5 %} disabled="" {% endif %} type="submit">
  {% if obj.ticket_waiting == True %}
   {{ solved_message }}
  {% else %}
  {{ waiting_message }}
  {% endif %}
</button>
</form>

<p> Changes: {{ obj.reopened_counter }} </p>

<br>
<h2>New Message</h2>
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ user_form }}
  <button type="submit">New Message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you saying in view `ticket_system_view` you should have way to execute one of the two forms either `TicketSolved` or `TicketMessagesForm`

Comment: I mean if I execute one, both get executed which is wrong

Comment: Create a separate view for user_form and specify the url in action attribute of form.

Comment: How should I have 2 different views rendering in just one HTML Template

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate template for your second form with separate route and use include template tag to include that template in your main template like this:

second_template.html:

```
 <form method="POST" action='second_view/'>
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ user_form }}
   <button type="submit">New Message</button>
 </form>
```

urls.py:

```
 path('second_view', views.second_view, name='second_view')
```

views.py:

```
def second_view(request, id):
    user_form = TicketMessagesForm(
        request.POST, instance=TicketMessages(id=id))
    if user_form.is_valid():
        instance = user_form.save(commit=False)
        #this form doesnt work yes
       instance.save()

     return render(request, 'second_template.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

And the last piece of puzzle is to include your second_template in your ticket_system so replace the second form with `{% include second_template.html  %}`. You can pass id to form just like you pass it in your original template.

Comment: @vize why was it unmarked as accepted?